# How to convert columns of a two dimensional array into row in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multidimensional-array

I have a two-dimensional python array that looks like this:

```
A = [[186,192,133],[12],[122,193,154],[166,188,199],[133,44,23,56,78,96,100]]
```

Now how do I make a new array that looks like this?

```
B = [[186,12,122,166,133],[192, 193,188,44],[133,154,199,23],[56],[78],[96],[100]]
```

I basically want to convert the column of A into rows of B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

```
from itertools import izip_longest # in Python 3 zip_longest

list([x for x in y if x is not None] for y in izip_longest(*A))
```

result:

```
[[186, 12, 122, 166, 133],
 [192, 193, 188, 44],
 [133, 154, 199, 23],
 [56],
 [78],
 [96],
 [100]]
```

### Explanation

`izip_longest` gives you an iterator:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> izip_longest([1, 2, 3], [4, 5])
<itertools.izip_longest at 0x103331890>
```

Convert it into a list to see what it does:

```
>>> list(izip_longest([1, 2, 3], [4, 5]))
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, None)]
```

It takes one element from each list and puts them pairwise into a tuple. Furthermore, it fills missing values with `None` ( or another value you supply).

The `*` allows to give a function an unspecified number of arguments. For example, we can put our two lists inside another list and use `*` and it still works the same:

```
>>> list(izip_longest(*[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]))
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, None)]
```

This is not limited to two arguments. An example with three.

Single arguments:

```
>>> list(izip_longest([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]))
[(1, 4, 6), (2, 5, None), (3, None, None)]
```

All arguments in one list with `*`:

```
>>> list(izip_longest(*[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]))
[(1, 4, 6), (2, 5, None), (3, None, None)]
```

You don't want the `None` values. Filter them out with a list comprehension:

```
>>> [x for x in y if x is not None]
```

For your `A`, you get this:

```
>>> list(izip_longest(*A))
[(186, 12, 122, 166, 133),
 (192, None, 193, 188, 44),
 (133, None, 154, 199, 23),
 (None, None, None, None, 56),
 (None, None, None, None, 78),
 (None, None, None, None, 96),
 (None, None, None, None, 100)]
```

Now, `y` runs through all entries in this list such as `(186, 12, 122, 166, 133)`. While `x` runs through each individual number in `y` such as `186`. The outer `[]`  creates a list. So instead of the tuple `(186, 12, 122, 166, 133)` 
we get a list `[186, 12, 122, 166, 133]`. Finally, the `if x is not None` filters out the `None` values.

Comment: I am very  new to python. I tried looking at its documentation, but I still can't understand Do you mind explaining why you put *A in izip_longest() ?

Comment: Added some background info.

Answer (score 1):

Another method transposing using `map` and `filter`:

```
A = [[186, 192, 133], [12], [122, 193, 154], [166, 188, 199], [133, 44, 23, 56, 78, 96, 100]]


print([list(filter(None,sub)) for sub in map(None,*A)])
[[186, 12, 122, 166, 133], [192, 193, 188, 44], [133, 154, 199, 23], [56], [78], [96], [100]]
```

If `0` is a potential you will need to specifically check for None's:

```
print([list(filter(lambda x: x is not None, sub)) for sub in map(None,*A)])
```

Or map with a regular list comp as per Mikes answer:

```
 [[x for x in sub if x is not None] for sub in map(None,*A)]
```

Comment: Is None a function? I am wondering how this map(None,*A) is working? Isn't it like map(function, iterable, ...)? I thought map() is like lapply() in R?

Answer (score 0):

```
    def rotate(A):
        B = []
        added = True
        while added:
            added = False
            col = []
            for row in A:
                try:
                    col.append(row.pop(0))
                except IndexError:
                    continue
                added = True
            col and B.append(col)
        return B
```